# RoR: submmiting a form is creating two ojects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create the index page containing all of the existing stablishments.
A link such that when you click on it a form for creating a new stablishment shows.

```
Controller:
  def index
    @stablishments = Stablishment.all
    @new_stablishment = Stablishment.new()
  end

  def create
    @stablishment = Stablishment.new
    @stablishment.update_attributes(params[:stablishment])
  end


Index:
Index

<div id="create_stablishment">
  <%= link_to "Crear Nuevo Establecimiento", '#' %>
</div>

<div id="stablishment_form_fields" style="display:none;">
  <%= form_for(@new_stablishment, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'stablishments/form_fields', :locals => {f: f} %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="stablishments_list">
  <% @stablishments.each_with_index do |stablishment, i| %>
    <%= render stablishment, :count => i %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="mensaje"></div>

form_fields:
<div class="form_fields">
  <%= f.label "Nombre" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="form_fields">
  <%= f.label "Ciudad" %>
  <%= f.text_field :city %>
</div>
<div class="form_fields">
  <%= f.label "Estado" %>
  <%= f.text_field :state %>
</div>
<div class="form_fields">
  <%= f.label "Direccion" %>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
</div>
<div class="form_fields">
  <%= f.label "Email" %>
  <%= f.text_field :mail %>
</div>
<div class="form_fields">
  <%= f.label "Sitio Web" %>
  <%= f.text_field :web_site %>
</div>
<div class="form_fields">
  <%= f.label "Tipo" %>
  <%= f.text_field :stablishment_type %>
</div>
<div class="form_fields">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
create.js:
$("#stablishment_form_fields").hide();
$("#mensaje").html("se ha creado");
```

When I click on create stablishments it is creating to objects. The log:

```
Started POST "/stablishments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-15 20:47:05 -0300
Processing by StablishmentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VDf47PuVfNH7UPLEyVqtY4n+2DgmCKT3Jvx2wljMtZY=", "stablishment"=>{"name"=>"6", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "address"=>"", "mail"=>"", "web_site"=>"", "stablishment_type"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Stablishment"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `stablishments` (`address`, `city`, `created_at`, `mail`, `name`, `phone`, `stablishment_type`, `state`, `updated_at`, `web_site`) VALUES ('', NULL, '2012-09-15 23:47:05', '', '6', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-09-15 23:47:05', '')
   (119.6ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered stablishments/create.js.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 176ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 120.2ms)


Started POST "/stablishments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-15 20:47:05 -0300
Processing by StablishmentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VDf47PuVfNH7UPLEyVqtY4n+2DgmCKT3Jvx2wljMtZY=", "stablishment"=>{"name"=>"6", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "address"=>"", "mail"=>"", "web_site"=>"", "stablishment_type"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Stablishment"}
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `stablishments` (`address`, `city`, `created_at`, `mail`, `name`, `phone`, `stablishment_type`, `state`, `updated_at`, `web_site`) VALUES ('', NULL, '2012-09-15 23:47:05', '', '6', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-09-15 23:47:05', '')
   (58.9ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered stablishments/create.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 76ms (Views: 10.3ms | ActiveRecord: 60.3ms)
```

why could this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are two requests were sent. It may the problem comes from the Javascript, because you are using the remote form.

```
form_for(@new_stablishment, :remote => true)
```

The AJAX post will be automatically setup and called by rails.js or jquery_ujs.js. So we don't need to manually handle it.

So to fix this issue, you can show the console log in the browser (I would like to use Firebug in Firefox). If there are two requests, it means that there is something wrong in your javascript code.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! what silly mistake from me. In my assets folder i had jquery-1.8.1 so the ajax part was being handled by two javascript files hence resulting in two requests.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating `@stablishment` and then calling `update_attributes` on it, just use:

```
def create
  @stablishment = Stablishment.new(params[:stablishment]).save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

User method create instead:

```
def create
  @stablishment = Stablishment.create(params[:stablishment])
end
```

Comment: thanks for both answers! i don't think that could fix the problem, in fact it didn't work.. i tried both suggestions and the problem is still there.. anyway thank you! i'll continue looking for a solution. More over, look that the problem is not that i'am saving two objects in the same action or something like that, look at the look, there are two POST /establishments. I tried doing a sleep 10 in the action and it waited the 10 seconds and the post was done again.. the problem is like you were doing two clicks!